# Flutter app does not grab location afgsr gos is turned off then on

Tags: dart, location, flutter

My application collects location data when the user presses on a certain button, but if the user turns gps option off then turns it back the location no more works even if the gps is enabled.How to handle such a thing in flutter??

Answer (score 0):

As per example in this link https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location you should put add below code in button's click event.

```
var location = new Location();

// Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
try {
  currentLocation = await location.getLocation;
} on PlatformException {
  currentLocation = null;
}
```

Comment: I will check and see if this works as intended in my application

Comment: I did as stated in the example but if the gps is turned if then the users turned it on again the location still fails to load .Any idea??